# Maxima minima of $f(x)=\frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, ceiling-and-floor-functions, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{\sqrt{x}}$

$$\forall x\in {]}0,+\infty{[},\quad 0\leq f(x)<1$$

- How can I show that $0$ is minimum value for $f$ and $1$ isn't maximum value for $f$

Comment: $x-\lfloor x \rfloor=1$, when $x \neq \text{integer}$ and it is $0$ at integers.

Answer (score 4):

Your function $f$ is non-negative because the numerator and the denominator are non-negative.

$f(1)=0$ so the minimum is zero.

For $x > 1$ the numerator is less than one and $\sqrt{x} > 1$ so $f$ is strictly less than one.
For $x \in]0,1[$, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ which is strictly less than one.

Comment: $1$ may not be the maximum, but this shows it is the supremum (least upper bound)